# What will be my function name in template.php for particular .tpl.php

Tags: theming

I have template.php and node--product.tpl.php files. What should be my function name in template.php to pass variable from template.php to .tpl.php

Here is template.php code

```
function mytheme_process_product(&$variables){  **//What should be my function name here**
$variables['temp_var']="This is demo Temporary Variable for Perticular Product .Tpl.php";
}
```

node--product.tpl.php

```
<?php print $temp_var; ?>
```

And my .tpl.php file name is node--product.tpl.php where product is my content type name.

Please reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use theme_preprocess_node function in template to add variables..

```
/**
 * Override or insert variables into the node templates.
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   An array of variables to pass to the theme template.
 * @param $hook
 *   The name of the template being rendered ("node" in this case.)
 */

function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {


  // define $node object, so it's be easier to use it
  $node = $variables['node'];

  // add variables to node--nameofnodetype.tpl.php file
  if ($node->type == 'product'){

      // $variables: an array with variables
      // you need to add one, so just define it
      $variables['my_variable'] = 'whatever';


  }
}
```

In your node--product.tpl.php file:

```
// check if your new variable exist
print $my_variable;
```

Comment: Just for curiosity..!!
Shall I use any function as mentioned above within question like
function mytheme_process_node__product(&$variables){}
to pass variables??

Comment: Yes.. You should.. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7 tell the same.. Check last two lines..